# Network reachability on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Maybe is there a good way to determine if I have an internet connection or not? (3G or wifi)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something a new search engine called Google revealed:

[iPhone SDK: Testing Network Reachability](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-testing-network-reachability/)

Comment: I am using this new feature of the internet, but it didn't give me this site ;) but anyway, thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

See SCNetworkReachabilityRef datatype in the SystemConfigration framework. It does not test the network per se, it's a framework around ping.